# Flume-- Could not find the main class: org.apache.flume.tools.GetJavaProperty

Tags: hadoop, flume

I am using cloudera CDH 4.4.When I ran the flume cmd -

```
"bin/flume-ng agent -n agentA -f conf/MultipleFlumes.properties -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console"
```

I got an error:

```
[cloudera@localhost Flume]$ bin/flume-ng agent -n agentA -f conf/MultipleFlumes.properties -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
Warning: No configuration directory set! Use --conf <dir> to override.
Info: Including Hadoop libraries found via (/usr/bin/hadoop) for HDFS access
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flume/tools/GetJavaProperty
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.tools.GetJavaProperty
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.flume.tools.GetJavaProperty.  Program will exit.
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar from classpath
Info: Excluding /usr/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar from classpath
Info: Including HBASE libraries found via (/usr/bin/hbase) for HBASE access
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flume/tools/GetJavaProperty
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.tools.GetJavaProperty
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.flume.tools.GetJavaProperty.  Program will exit.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flume/node/Application
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flume.node.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.apache.flume.node.Application.  Program will exit.
```

I tried to echo HADOOP_HOME but it returned blank. What is the problem in above command?
Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, add the `-c` parameter to the command like this:

```
bin/flume-ng agent -n agentA -c conf -f conf/MultipleFlumes.properties -Dflume.root.logger=INFO,console
```

Adding that parameter does not resolve the issue but if you don't include it you get another error because of log4j configuration file.

As for your problem, check if `FLUME_HOME` is defined, and if that is the case, unset it with

```
unset FLUME_HOME
```